# Filled many Textbox with Select box using laravel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel-8

I want to display data in a text box based on the selected options. for example if If I select the title of the book, it will display the author of the book, the price of the book, the year the book was printed.
I want to display the book based on the selected option chosen

my Controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\P_Peminjaman;
use App\Models\M_Asset;
use App\Models\M_Perpustakaan;
use App\Models\User;

class P_PeminjamanController extends Controller
{
public function getpengarang_buku(Request $request)
    {
        $kode_buku = $request->kode_buku;
        $perpustakaan = Regency::where('buku_kode', $kode_buku)->get();

        foreach($perpustakaan as $buku){
            echo "<input id='$buku->pengarang_buku' type='text' class='$buku->pengarang_buku'>";
            echo "<input id='$buku->penerbit_buku' type='text' class='$buku->penerbit_buku'>";
        }
    }
}
```

my Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class M_Perpustakaan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "m_perpustakaan";
}
```

my javascript

```
$(function()
    {
        $('#judul_buku').on('change', function(){
            let kode_buku = $('#judul_buku').val();

            // console.log(kode_buku);
            $.ajax({
              headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
              type : 'POST',
              url : "{{ route('getpengarang_buku') }}",
              data : {kode_buku:kode_buku},
              cache : false,

             success: function(msg){
                $('#pengarang_buku').html(msg);
                $('#penerbit_buku').html(msg);
               }
              
            })
        })
    });
```

my web.php

```
Route::post('/getpengarang_buku',[P_PeminjamanController::class, 'getpengarang_buku'])->name('getpengarang_buku');
```

my create.blade.php

```
<head><meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" /></head>
<body>
<select class="form-control" name="judul_buku" id="judul_buku">
                        <option value="">- Pilih Buku -</option>
                        @foreach ($buku as $item)
                        <option value="{{ $item->kode_buku }}">{{ $item->judul_buku }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>

<input type="text" name="pengarang_buku" class="form-control" placeholder="Info pengarang_buku" id="pengarang_buku" value="{{ old('pengarang_buku') }}">

<input type="text" name="penerbit_buku" class="form-control" placeholder="Info penerbit_buku" id="penerbit_buku" value="{{ old('penerbit_buku') }}">

</body>
```

but the result can't be found in the textbox at all, can anyone help me? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to add return at your controller, its better to return the value from your request with json like this rather than echo value

```
public function getpengarang_buku(Request $request)
{
    $kode_buku = $request->kode_buku;
    $perpustakaan = Regency::where('buku_kode', $kode_buku)->get();
    $data = [];
    foreach($perpustakaan as $buku){
        $data = ['pengarang_buku' => $buku->pengarang_buku,
                'penerbit_buku' => $buku->penerbit_buku];
    }
    return response()->json($data); 
}
```

and in ajax response just pass the value to input text

```
 $(function()
{
    $('#judul_buku').on('change', function(){
        let kode_buku = $('#judul_buku').val();

        // console.log(kode_buku);
        $.ajax({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
          type : 'POST',
          url : "{{ route('getpengarang_buku') }}",
          data : {kode_buku:kode_buku},
          cache : false,

         success: function(msg){
            $('#pengarang_buku').val(msg['pengarang_buku']);
            $('#penerbit_buku').val(msg['penerbit_buku']
           }
          
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I fixed it a bit here: $('#penerbit_buku').val(msg['penerbit_buku']);
but i have problem with error : 500 (Internal Server Error). can you help me again? where do you think I went wrong?

Comment: `error 500 (Internal Server Error)` is linked with this question?

Comment: My fault, it turns out that I was missing 1 letter in the controller. it is working for me now, Thank you very much, really helped me, God bless you and stay healthy

Comment: yo, sama-sama :)